# android simple file browser

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to implement *simple file browser* to *select folder* in my app.I have almost done it but something got wrong.I have got a *list view* with *single choice mode* to list files. *No error shown* but same folders are being listed upto 4 times and the positions are also changing, when i scroll the listView. I have got no idea what is wrong even though I am very much familiar with ListView.
Here is part of my activity -

```
    setContentView(R.layout.selectfolder);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.folderlistView);
    select=(Button) findViewById(R.id.fSelect);
    cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.fCancel);
    path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    item=new ArrayList<String>();
    itemPath=new ArrayList<String>();
    loadDirectory(path);}

private void loadDirectory(String path) {
    item.clear();
    itemPath.clear();
    FileFilter filterDirectoriesOnly=new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0.isDirectory();
        }
    };
    File file=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File[] files=file.listFiles(filterDirectoriesOnly);
    System.out.println("file size is"+files.length);
    for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
        File f=files[i];
            item.add(f.getName());
            itemPath.add(f.getPath().split("emulated")[1]);
    }
    System.out.println("item size is"+item.size());
    aa=new FolderArrayAdapter(FolderSelect.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,item);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

and my custom array adapter here--

```
ArrayList<String> item;
public FolderArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.item=objects;
}
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=convertView;
    LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(v==null){
        v=li.inflate(R.layout.folderlisttext, parent, false);
        TextView t=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.foldertext);
        t.setText(item.get(position));}
    return v;
}
```

I have spent a few hours to know the reason of this, but failed. Please share some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
aa=new FolderArrayAdapter(FolderSelect.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemPath);
```

to

```
 aa=new FolderArrayAdapter(FolderSelect.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,item);
```

Comment: Edited: it was originally 'aa=new FolderArrayAdapter(FolderSelect.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,item);'

Comment: I doesn't see the problem. I think you need logged your app or use debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
 t.setText(item.get(position));
```

You should do that always. Not only when v==null.

Comment: It shouldn't be done when 'v!=null' I think, because view should be created only when it is null or not created before. Even though I tried but problem remains.